# Configure SSL on NGINX reverse proxy on GCP VM

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, https, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a GCP VM instance running a NodeJS server and it has a Nginx reverse proxy configured that allows me to connect with the NodeJS server over HTTP. The server is also accessible through a domain name (The Domain was purchase from Google Domains and I did not explicitly buy a SSL certificate)

I want to configure HTTPS on this VM instance.

I tried to use certbot and follow the instructions here https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntubionic-nginx

but I still cannot connect to my NodeJS server over HTTPS.

Please note: HTTP traffic works fine when connecting through IP and domain name.

Comment: Hi there! Please add more information about the error. If you can share more information (error screens, error logs, etc) we can better assist you

Comment: I don't get any errors. Every time I try to hit my domain on server IP using HTTPS the connection will just timeout!

Comment: The timeout is the error. So, if you go using IP like https://<VM EXTERNAL IP>:443 you do not get a timeout but if you go by domain you get a timeout?

Comment: I get a timeout when using both VM EXTERNAL IP as well as domain

NOT WORKING:
https://<VM EXERNAL IP>/


WORKING:
http://<VM EXERNAL IP>/

Comment: You should be able to see nginx logs when you hit the https domain. Did you configure nginx to listen SSL/443?

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. But it turns out Nginx was configured correctly, but Ubuntu firewall was blocking connections to port 443.

just did `sudo ufw allow https` and everything started working.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this.

Turns out, that the firewall was blocking connections to port 443.

For readers:
On GCP VM make sure firewalls are configured correctly at 3 places.

1. GCP Networking Firewall should be configured to allows http/https/SSH/etc
2. Your VM should be set with proper GCP Firewall tags so that your GCP Firewall configuration is applied to your VM.
3. Your OS Firewall should be configured to allow the traffic you want.